# python schedule script code snippet

Tags: python, file

```
 <_io.TextIOWrapper name='output.html' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Error while trying to compile the json string to send: 'Content'
```

#### a scheduled script is throwing above error.

Its running on scheduled timings but the mail is not sent.

Comment: The question is not clear, please provide a more detailed and well-explained one. Flagged as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Provide more information @Parameshwari J because this doesn't help me understanding the question at all

Comment: That's not an error message, it is the representation of an IO object when you print it.  Looks like you are passing an IO object to something that expects a string.

Comment: i am trying to send  content from 'output.html' using mail